# How to persist spring-boot-admin-starter-server service data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, monitoring, prometheus, spring-boot-admin

For monitoring spring boot applications we create an admin service (**spring-boot-admin-starter-server**), its working fine only problem is we need to store that data, like can we store this data to Prometheus.

Found another solution that Prometheus will pick the data from each service, but we don't want to use that way because if the machine will be added dynamically we have put new service configuration in Prometheus every time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check Spring Metrics project, here is documentations:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-metrics/docs/current/public/prometheus

Comment: Thanks, requerment is something different, if the auto-scaling is on and any machine added and run time, how the Prometheus will know so this machine can also be monitored.

Comment: Also, the spring-boot-admin-starter-server is working fine for me but not found any solution to store this data.